# Attaching AWS documentDB to Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I've recently tried using the new AWS DocumentDB service as my DB in a Spring application.

The cluster has been created in the same VPC as the EKS on which I deploy my application. Security groups allow connections between all nodes in the VPC.

AWS exposes a mongo URI like this for my DB cluster:

```
mongodb://<my-user>:<insertYourPassword>@<my-cluster-endpoint>:27017/?ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0
```

My question:

How do I make my Spring code work with this kind of connection?

I have tried adding the followig to my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<my-user>:<insertYourPassword>@<my-cluster-endpoint>:27017/admin?ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs00
spring.data.mongodb.database=admin
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

And placing the PEM file in `/src/main/resources`

However the code still fails to connect to the DB cluster.

I get this message as an error: `No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate`

Followed by a `Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ...`

And finally a timeout exception: `com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message`

It looks kind of like a security group issue but I have no problem connecting with mongo shell from the same EC2 running the Spring application Pod.

Any ideas?

Comment: whats the exception, share some logs.

Comment: use this guide https://braytonstafford.com/2018/03/27/importing-aws-rds-pem-certificate-to-java-keystore/ to extract jks from aws ca bundle.

Comment: did u find a solution ? I am having the same problem

Comment: I unfortunately had to abandon this side project for the moment. Will update should anything change and a solution be found. Apologies to all those who chimed in, once time allows I'll go through the suggestions.

Comment: @TheFooBarWay did you get any solution for this. My use case is also same, spring boot application running in AWS EKS and accessing AWS Document DB. The EKS cluster and Document DB are in same VPC. I get the same error as you.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the documentation,

> By design, you access Amazon DocumentDB (with MongoDB compatibility) resources from an Amazon EC2 instance within the same Amazon VPC as the Amazon DocumentDB resources. However, suppose that your use case requires that you or your application access your Amazon DocumentDB resources from outside the cluster's Amazon VPC. In that case, you can use SSH tunneling (also known as "port forwarding") to access your Amazon DocumentDB resources.

[Connect from outside VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html)

> Your Amazon DocumentDB cluster should be running in your default virtual private cloud (VPC). To interact with your Amazon DocumentDB cluster, you must launch an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance into your default VPC, in the same AWS Region where you created your Amazon DocumentDB cluster.

Follow the guide to connect to the cluster 
[AWS DocumentDB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/getting-started.launch-ec2-instance.html)

**GitHub Reference**: [spring-boot-aws-documentdb](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-boot-aws-documentdb)

**Update**:

To connect through SSL, use below logic by setting **SSL_CERTIFICATE** pointing to aws region specific intermediate certificate.

This can be downloaded from [SSL certs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) and copy it to base directory. 
Alternatively, you can provide absolute path to the variable **SSL_CERTIFICATE**.

```
     private static final String SSL_CERTIFICATE = "rds-ca-2015-us-east-1.pem";
     private static final String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "JKS";
     private static final String KEY_STORE_PROVIDER = "SUN";
     private static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_PREFIX = "sys-connect-via-ssl-test-cacerts";
     private static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jks";
     private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "changeit";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSLContextHelper.setSslProperties();
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    protected static class SSLContextHelper{
    /**
     * This method sets the SSL properties which specify the key store file, its type and password:
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static void setSslProperties()  {

        try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", createKeyStoreFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", KEY_STORE_TYPE);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
    }


    private static String createKeyStoreFile() throws Exception {
        return createKeyStoreFile(createCertificate()).getPath();
    }

    /**
     *  This method generates the SSL certificate
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static X509Certificate createCertificate() throws Exception {
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        URL url = new File(SSL_CERTIFICATE).toURI().toURL();
        if (url == null) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        try (InputStream certInputStream = url.openStream()) {
            return (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method creates the Key Store File
     * @param rootX509Certificate - the SSL certificate to be stored in the KeyStore
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static File createKeyStoreFile(X509Certificate rootX509Certificate) throws Exception {
        File keyStoreFile = File.createTempFile(KEY_STORE_FILE_PREFIX, KEY_STORE_FILE_SUFFIX);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile.getPath())) {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE, KEY_STORE_PROVIDER);
            ks.load(null);
            ks.setCertificateEntry("rootCaCertificate", rootX509Certificate);
            ks.store(fos, DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        }
        return keyStoreFile;
    }


    }
```

**connection output**:

```
019-01-17 13:33:22.316  INFO 3598 --- [onaws.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Canonical address mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 does not match server address.  Removing mongodb.cluster-cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 from client view of cluster
2019-01-17 13:33:22.401  INFO 3598 --- [onaws.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2}] to mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
2019-01-17 13:33:22.403  INFO 3598 --- [onaws.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=2132149, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017, hosts=[mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000001, setVersion=null, lastWriteDate=Thu Jan 17 13:33:21 UTC 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=516261208876}
2019-01-17 13:33:22.406  INFO 3598 --- [onaws.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
2019-01-17 13:33:22.595  INFO 3598 --- [           main] com.barath.app.CustomerService           : Saving the customer with customer details com.barath.app.Customer@6c130c45
2019-01-17 13:33:22.912  INFO 3598 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3}] to mongodb.cktoiipu3bbd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
2019-01-17 13:33:23.936  INFO 3598 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
```

Comment: It was working but all other https call are failing even aws sdk call. Gettting PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
 unable to find valid certification path to requested. Any idea?

Comment: @mmr25 you have issues with cer path, follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

Comment: @mmr25 I am also facing same issue had you solved it?

Comment: @Afsaredrisy here is my solution hope that works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/69355551/6629184

Comment: @mmr25, I solved it using netty client for documentdb. please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230901/attaching-aws-documentdb-to-spring-boot-application/#answer-72824511

Answer (score 7):

The answer provided by [@Sunny Pelletier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984327/sunny-pelletier) worked for me with a mashup of [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278949/frank)'s answer in our Java setup.

So for me, I wanted a solution that worked for our local docker setup and for any of our AWS environments that have active profiles and other env vars set in our environment via the CDK.

I first started with a simple Configuration POJO to setup my properties outside the `spring.data.mongo.*` paradigm. You don't have to do this and can just let Spring handle it as it normally does to create the `MongoClient`.

My default local dev `application.yml` and corresponding config class.

```yaml
mongo:
  user: mongo
  password: mongo
  host: localhost
  port: 27017
  database: my-service
```

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongo")
public class MongoConnectConfig {

    private int port;

    private String host;

    private String user;

    private String database;

    private String password;

}
```

Then, I created two `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` child classes; one for local and one for non-local. The key here is that I didn't create my own `MongoClient`. The reason is because I want all the good Spring Boot initialization stuff that you get with the framework. For example, the auto-registration of all the converters and such.

Instead, I leveraged the customization hook provided by `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration.configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder)` to then aggregate the custom settings like the `.pem` piece.

The other part is that I leveraged profiles to enable/disable the configurations to make it "seamless" for local developers; we don't use any profiles other than `default` for local development so it's easier to get setup without having to "know" so much from the start.

```java
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Profile({"!dev && !qa && !prod"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "co.my.data.repositories")
public class LocalDevMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    
    private final MongoConnectConfig config;
    
    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return config.getDatabase();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder) {
        log.info("Applying Local Dev MongoDB Configuration");
        builder.applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(getConnectionString()));
    }

    //mongodb://${mongo.user}:${mongo.password}@${mongo.host}:${mongo.port}/${mongo.database}?authSource=admin
    private String getConnectionString() {
        return String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?authSource=admin",
                config.getUser(),
                config.getPassword(),
                config.getHost(),
                config.getPort(),
                config.getDatabase()
        );
    }
}
```

```java
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Profile({"dev || qa || prod"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "co.my.data.repositories")
public class DocumentDbMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    private final MongoConnectConfig config;

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return config.getDatabase();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder) {
        log.info("Applying AWS DocumentDB Configuration");
        builder.applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(getConnectionString()));
        var endOfCertificateDelimiter = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        File resource = new ClassPathResource("certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem").getFile();
        String pemContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath()));
        var allCertificates = Arrays.stream(pemContents
                .split(endOfCertificateDelimiter))
                .filter(line -> !line.isBlank())
                .map(line -> line + endOfCertificateDelimiter)
                .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());


        var certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        // This allows us to use an in-memory key-store
        keyStore.load(null);

        for (int i = 0; i < allCertificates.size(); i++) {
            var certString = allCertificates.get(i);
            var caCert = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certString.getBytes()));
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry(String.format("AWS-certificate-%s", i), caCert);
        }

        var trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

        var sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

        builder.applyToSslSettings(ssl -> {
            ssl.enabled(true).context(sslContext);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Partly based on the AWS Console "Connectivity & security " section in the DocumentDB Cluster View.
     *   Since we register the pem above, we don't need to add the ssl & sslCAFile piece
     *   mongodb://${user}:${password}@${host}:${port}/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
     */
    private String getConnectionString() {
        return String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false",
                config.getUser(),
                config.getPassword(),
                config.getHost(),
                config.getPort(),
                config.getDatabase()
        );
    }
}
```

Lastly, we place the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` in the `src/main/resources/certs/` folder.

**Side Notes:**

- Again, I believe you should be able to get away with using the default `spring.data*` properties and your `MongoClient` should have used them.
- Ignore the `@SneakyThrows` here, I just did that for code brevity purposes, handle your checked exceptions as you see fit.
- I guess we can see why Kotlin syntax can be considered "cleaner" huh? :)

Comment: Getting this: "error: variable config not initialized in the default constructor". I'm guessing that means the `RequiredArgsConstructor` isn't working, correct? I must be missing a dependency.

Comment: Did you bring in and is your project configured for Lombok? If not, you can just manually create your constructor.

Comment: I was just missing a dependency for the annotation processor. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm the solution provided by @Barath allows you to secure the AWS DocumentDB TLS connection inside the Java application itself. This is a much cleaner approach compared to the one described by AWS on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html which requires you to run a script on your server which is more complicated and difficult for automated deploys etc.

To further set up the connection itself in the Spring application I used the following @Configuration class, which allows you to connect to a local MongoDB for testing during development, and the AWS one once deployed with settings from the properties file.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
    
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "YOUR.PACKAGE.WITH.repository")
public class MongoDbConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;
    
    @Value("${mongodb.host:localhost}")
    private String dbUri;
    @Value("${mongodb.port:27017}")
    private int dbPort;
    @Value("${mongodb.database.name:YOUR_DOCUMENTDB_NAME}")
    private String dbName;
    @Value("${mongodb.username:}")
    private String dbUser;
    @Value("${mongodb.password:}")
    private String dbPassword;
    
    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return dbName;
    }
    
    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(getConnectionString());
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
               .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
               .build();
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }
    
    private String getConnectionString() {
        if (activeProfile.contains("local")) {
            return String.format("mongodb://%s:%s/%s", dbUri, dbPort, dbName);
        }
        return String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readpreference=secondaryPreferred&retrywrites=false",
                dbUser, dbPassword, dbUri, dbPort, dbName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually faced the same issue as you did, but now AWS uses `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` which combines together many certificates into one.

If you don't want to create a trust-store using their outdated documentation, you can do it yourself and have the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` into your application generating the key-store at runtime.

I managed to get this to work with this code sample. This has been tested with `spring:2.4`, `mongo-driver: 4.1.1` and documentDB using `mongo 4.0` compatibility.

```kotlin
val endOfCertificateDelimiter = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

// rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem contains more than one certificate. We need to add them all to the trust-store independantly. 

val allCertificates = ClassPathResource("certificates/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem").file.readText()
    .split(endOfCertificateDelimiter)
    .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
    .map { it + endOfCertificateDelimiter }

val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
keyStore.load(null) // This allows us to use an in-memory key-store

allCertificates.forEachIndexed { index, certificate ->
    val caCert = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificate.byteInputStream()) as X509Certificate
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("AWS-certificate-$index", caCert)
}

val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)

val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, null)

builder.applyToSslSettings {
    it.enabled(true)
        .context(sslContext)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me just call the setSslProperties method before you connect to your documentdb.

```
    /**
 * This method sets the SSL properties which specify the key store file, its type and password.
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static void setSslProperties() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", createKeyStoreFile());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", KEY_STORE_TYPE);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
}

/**
 * This method returns the path of the Key Store File needed for the SSL verification during the IAM Database Authentication to
 * the db instance.
 *
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static String createKeyStoreFile() throws Exception {
    return createKeyStoreFile(createCertificate()).getPath();
}

/**
 * This method generates the SSL certificate.
 *
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static X509Certificate createCertificate() throws Exception {
    final CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    final ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
    final InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(SSL_CERTIFICATE);
    return (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(is);

}

/**
 * This method creates the Key Store File.
 *
 * @param rootX509Certificate - the SSL certificate to be stored in the KeyStore
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static File createKeyStoreFile(final X509Certificate rootX509Certificate) throws Exception {
    final File keyStoreFile = File.createTempFile(KEY_STORE_FILE_PREFIX, KEY_STORE_FILE_SUFFIX);
    try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile.getPath())) {
        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE, KEY_STORE_PROVIDER);
        ks.load(null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("rootCaCertificate", rootX509Certificate);
        ks.store(fos, DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    }
    return keyStoreFile;
}
```

Here are the constants.

```
public static final String SSL_CERTIFICATE = "rds-ca-2019-root.pem";
public static final String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "JKS";
public static final String KEY_STORE_PROVIDER = "SUN";
public static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_PREFIX = "sys-connect-via-ssl-test-cacerts";
public static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jks";
public static final String DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "changeit";
```

Here is the [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2021-root.pem) for rds-ca-2019-root.pem file place that file inder resources folder.

let me know this works for you.

Here is a sample

```
       setSslProperties();
        final MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, mongoProps.getDatabaseName(), password.toCharArray());
        final MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .credential(credential)
                .readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
                .retryWrites(false)
                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true))
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(connPoolBuilder ->
                        ConnectionPoolSettings.builder().
                                maxSize(1).build())
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                        builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(clusterEndPoint, 27017))))
                .build();
        mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

Comment: Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @mmr25 in comments to @Barath answer, The solution only works for when service needs to only connect to documentDB. You start getting **"Gettting PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested"** for other http requests.

To address this issue we need to only enable sslcontext for documentdb connections. To do we can use Netty as HttpClient for mongodb connections. To enable netty we need to add following maven dependency to your spring boot project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.53.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and put your pem file in your resources folder and define following beans in one of the class annotated with @Configutation annotations.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class MongoDbConfiguration {

    private static final String AWS_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME = "rds-ca-2019-root.pem";

    private final String mongoConnectionUri;

    private final String databaseName;

    public MongoDbConfiguration(@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}") String mongoConnectionUri, @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}") String databaseName) {
        this.mongoConnectionUri = mongoConnectionUri;
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    @SneakyThrows
    @Profile("!default")
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {

        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
                .trustManager(new ClassPathResource(AWS_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME).getInputStream())
                .build();

        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(mongoConnectionUri);

        return MongoClients.create(
                MongoClientSettings.builder()
                        .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                        .applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                            builder.enabled((null == connectionString.getSslEnabled()) ? false : connectionString.getSslEnabled());
                            builder.invalidHostNameAllowed((null == connectionString.getSslInvalidHostnameAllowed()) ? false : connectionString.getSslInvalidHostnameAllowed());
                        })
                        .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.builder()
                                .sslContext(sslContext)
                                .build())
                        .build());
    }
}
```

Import Statements:

```
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslProvider;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager;
```

Now you should be able to connect to your documentdb and other http connection should also work as expected.

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/connection/tls/#customize-tls-ssl-configuration-through-the-netty-sslcontext

Answer (score -5):

The Simple solution is you can remove the TLS (SSL) option in AWS, then you can remove the "ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem" from your connection string.  But if the application required the SSL DB connectivity, then you can use the
[AWS Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html)